# Is it known if $\mathrm{CFL} \subseteq\mathrm{ NSPACE}(o(log^2(n)))$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, context-free, logspace

$\mathrm{CFL}$ is the class of context-free languages.

> **Question**
>
> Is $\mathrm{CFL}$ known to be solvable in $o(log^{2}(n))$ non-deterministic space? What about $\mathrm{DCFL}$?

Comment: Also see related question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/is-cfl-strictly-contained-in-nl

Comment: Yes. This is Theorem 4 in the following paper. Philip M. Lewis II, Richard Edwin Stearns, Juris Hartmanis:
Memory bounds for recognition of context-free and context-sensitive languages. SWCT (FOCS) 1965: 191-202. Edit: I am sorry. My answer is not helpful. I missed the "small o". Stupid... I am not sure what to do. Delete the answer?

Comment: Theorem 4 only shows the $\log^2 n$ bound?

Comment: Thank you @Hsien-ChihChang張顯之 !  Yes, I might not have made my question clear enough.  I was asking if we can do better than $\log^2(n)$ space.  I updated the question changing "less than" to little oh to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Also, thank you @Thomas for including the reference to the classic paper.  :)

Comment: Comment about DCFL's being solvable in less space was removed as it only applied to a certain class of DCFL's.  See here for more info: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31644-9_13

Comment: How about logcfl?

Comment: If $L$ is CF then $L = \varphi( R \cap Dick_k)$ where R is regular, Dick_k is the Dyck language over k symbols and $\varphi$ is an homomorphism. Didn't think about it too much, but $R \cap Dick_k$ should be solvable in $DSPACE(\log(n))$. So a parallel more general problem could be: given $L \in  CFL$ and $\varphi$ homomorphism, if $L$ is recognized in $NSPACE(o(\log^2(n)))$, can $\varphi^{-1}(L)$ be recognized in $NSPACE( o(\log^2(n)) )$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not known whether CFL is contained in space o(log^2(n)). If CFL were contained in space o(log^2(n)), then NL would also be contained in space o(log^2(n)). The question whether NL is contained in space o(log^2(n)) is surprisingly still an open question in complexity theory.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  Is this because there is an NL-complete problem in CFL?

Comment: Oh, maybe this follows because NL is a subset of logCFL and CFL in space o(log^2(n)) would imply that logCFL in o(log^2(n)).  Cool!  Thank you again for pointing this out!  :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  My original question had to do with nspace, not dspace.  This is great, but doesn't seem to lead to conclusions about the original question.